Spring config server | client doesn't access second propertySource
i just implemented an config server for my application, with the following structure in my config-repo
/
   > application.properties
   > application-test.properties
   > application-dev.properties
   > application-prod.properties
/test-service
   > application.properties
   > application-test.properties
   > application-dev.properties
   > application-prod.properties

When i access the config-server over this url http://localhost:8102/test-service/dev
then i get this back.
{
  "name": "test-service",
  "profiles": [
    "dev"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": "cdf1f2b381b4acf9b48f2c9787379a0efaec582d",
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": ".../test-service/application.properties",
      "source": {
         "test2": "test2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": ".../application-dev.properties",
      "source": {
        "test": "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": ".../application.properties",
      "source": {
        "spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size": "5MB",
        "spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size": "5MB"
      }
    }
  ]
}

But for some reason, the service can only access the Data of the first entry of the propertySources Arry. It completly ignores the other ones.
This is the config i have in my microservice to access the config-service
spring.cloud.config.uri: http://localhost:8102
spring.config.import: optional:http://localhost:8102/
spring.cloud.config.name: test-service
spring.cloud.config.failFast=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=false
spring.cloud.config.profile: dev

